# FakeFS and Rspec incosistency with Rspec and real filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, filesystems, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write some tests involving file operations. I want to use some fake file system (something like VCR for external services) and I have found [fakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs). Unfortunately, either I can't set it right or something is broken (which I doubt, it's quite basic function), I've prepared simple example which illustrates what I mean, let the code speak:

With real FS:

```
module MyModule
  describe Something do

    before(:all) do
      File.open("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt", 'w+') { |f| f.write 'content'}
    end

    it 'should exist' do
      expect(Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt").exist?).to be_true
    end       

    it 'should still exist' do
      expect(Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt").exist?).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

Running that gives:

```
bash-4.2$ rspec
..

Finished in 0.00161 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Adding `fakeFS` in such way:

```
require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'

module MyModule
  describe Something do
  include FakeFS::SpecHelpers

    FakeFS.activate!
    FakeFS::FileSystem.clone(Rails.root)

    before(:all) do
      File.open("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt", 'w+') { |f| f.write 'content'}
    end

    it 'should exist' do
      expect(Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt").exist?).to be_true
    end       

    it 'should still exist' do
      expect(Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt").exist?).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

results in:

```
bash-4.2$ rspec
.F

Failures:

  1) MyModule::Something should still exist
     Failure/Error: expect(Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/foo.txt").exist?).to be_true
       expected: true value
            got: false
     # ./spec/models/something_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MyModule>'

Finished in 0.00354 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

So it seems like file is not persisted through subsequent tests. Do I misunderstand how `before(:all)` works or do I do something wrong? If so then why that code works with real files?

If it is 'not a bug, just a feature' then is there any other fake filesystem gem which is consistent with real one? Or do I have to stay with real files to get tests that.. well, test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer just after creating that question, duh ;) I've looked into source of that lib and found [suspicious line](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs/blob/master/lib/fakefs/spec_helpers.rb#L37).

Instead of `FakeFS::SpecHelpers` I've included `FakeFS::SpecHelpers::All` which is the same code except `FakeFS::FileSystem` is not being cleared after each call, now it behaves correctly.

Comment: What do you mean include FakeFS::SpecHelpers::All? did you include it in each file that uses fakefs? or in the spec_helper.rb?

Comment: I mean `spec_helper.rb`.